# While Loop and If Statements and functions

Tags: c++, function, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I don't know how to continue the loop indefinitely by only closing when I hit 'n' or 'N'... Once I put anything it eventually closes so how do I get back into the loop?

```
int counter = 5;
while(counter > 1)
linear(xcoordinateone, xcoordinatetwo, ycoordinateone, ycoordinatetwo, slope, intercept); //calling
{
cout<<"The points you entered define the function: y = " << slope << xone << "+" << intercept;
cout << "\n Do you want to continue?";
if (answer == 'N' || answer == 'n');    
    cin >> answer;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In addition to the input, you should review your `if`-conditions and make sure you don't use `=` when meaning `==`.

Comment: Did you mean `linear(...` to be inside the `{ }` ? As you have it, the loop body is just that call to `linear`; and then the `{` starts a new block that is unrelated to the loop

Answer (score 1):

You can but multiple conditions in your while loop:

```
answer = 'y';
while(answer != 'N' && answer != 'n'){
    cout << "\n Do you want to continue?";
    cin >> answer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
    // do stuff
    cout << "\n Do you want to continue?";
    cin >> answer;
} while (answer!='N' && answer!='n');
```